# Unable to query graphql endpoint

Tags: rust, graphql

I am trying to query a graphql endpoint using graphql_client and hit an error.

Here is the code:

```rust
extern crate serde_derive;

use gql_client::Client;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct DevActivity {
    pub data: Data,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Data {
    #[serde(rename = "getMetric")]
    pub get_metric: GetMetric,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct GetMetric {
    #[serde(rename = "timeseriesData")]
    pub timeseries_data: Vec<TimeseriesDatum>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct TimeseriesDatum {
    pub datetime: String,
    pub value: i64,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let query = r#"
            query getMetric(metric: "dev_activity") {
                    timeseriesData(
                        slug: "ethereum"
                        from: "2020-02-10T07:00:00Z"
                        to: "2020-03-10T07:00:00Z"
                        interval: "1w"
                    ) {
                        datetime
                        value
                }
                    }
        "#;

    let endpoint = "https://api.santiment.net/graphql";
    let client = Client::new(endpoint);

    let response = client.query::<DevActivity>(query).await.unwrap().unwrap();

    for data in &response.data.get_metric.timeseries_data {

        println!("datetime {}, value {}", data.datetime, data.value)
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

and here is the error:

```bash
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: 
GQLClient Error: Look at json field for more details
Message: syntax error before: "metric"
', src/main.rs:48:61
```

the expected response

```json
{"data":{"getMetric":{"timeseriesData":[{"datetime":"2020-02-13T00:00:00Z","value":1281.0},{"datetime":"2020-02-20T00:00:00Z","value":1115.0},{"datetime":"2020-02-27T00:00:00Z","value":952.0},{"datetime":"2020-03-05T00:00:00Z","value":605.0}]}}}
```

Cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "gql-client-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
gql_client = "1.0.4"
serde = { version = "1.0.137", features = ["derive"] }
tokio = { version = "1.19.2", features = ["full"] }
serde_derive = "1.0.126"
```

I would appreciate any pointers on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query isn't valid GraphQL. `getMetric` isn't a query - instead, you need to call it like this:

```
{
  getMetric(metric: "dev_activity") {
    timeseriesData(slug: "ethereum", from: "2020-02-10T07:00:00Z", to: "2020-03-10T07:00:00Z", interval: "1w") {
      datetime
      value
    }
  }
}
```

[(see on GraphiQL)](https://api.santiment.net/graphiql?query=%7B%0A%20%20getMetric(metric%3A%20%22dev_activity%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20timeseriesData(slug%3A%20%22ethereum%22%2C%20from%3A%20%222020-02-10T07%3A00%3A00Z%22%2C%20to%3A%20%222020-03-10T07%3A00%3A00Z%22%2C%20interval%3A%20%221w%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20datetime%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)